# How can I pass two queryset on the same page?? (django rest framework and react)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I want to show two queryset value in the same url. I have my homepage where I am passing all products list and after that section on the same page I am trying to show product based on category like this first recent products then next section all bikes(based on category).

```
@api_view(['GET'])

def getProducts(request):

     products = Product.objects.all()

     p = Product.objects.all().filter(category = 1)


   context = {
        "request": request,
    }
    
first_serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many= True, context=context)
second_serializer = ProductSerializer(p, many= True, context=context)

response = first_serializer.data + second_serializer.data
return Response(response)
```

this is my react page

#### **Recent Products**

---

```
        {loading ? <Loader />
            : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                :
                <Row>
                    {products.map(product => (
                        <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                            <Product product={product} />
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>     
            }
```

I want the same procedure  like this

```
 <Row>
                    {p.map((product) => (
                        <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                            <Product product={product} />
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>  

            
             <Row>
```

but I couldn't able to map the p object. what should I do now? I am using react with redux.